# Empty class in std::tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, language-lawyer, sizeof

> The size of any object or member subobject is required to be at least
>   1 even if the type is an empty class type [...], in order to be able
>   to guarantee that the addresses of distinct objects of the same type
>   are always distinct.

<sub>[cppreference quote](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo)</sub>

This I knew. What I just found out is that some library types, like `std::tuple` don't use any size for contained empty classes. Is this true? If yes, how is that ok?

---

Edit: after reading @bolov's final note on his answer I still one question: since `Empty` is `POD` it is safe to `memcpy` to it. But if you would memcpy to a "phantom" address (see @bolov's answer) you would effectively write inside an `int` element (`sizoef(Empty)` is 1). That doesn't seem ok.

Comment: Yes, I have split personalities... No I don't!.. Nobody asked you!.. Is anybody hungry?.. No, we are in the middle of something... Actually a pizza would sound nice...

Answer (score 6):

The size of an **object** must be greater than zero. The size of a **subobject** does not have that constraint. This leads to the Empty Base Optimization (EBO), in which an empty base class does not take up space (compilers started implementing this nearly 20 years ago). And that, in turn, leads to the usual implementation of `std::tuple` as an inheritance chain, in which empty base classes don't take up space.

Comment: It seems so easy when you put it like that... ;-) The other answer just describes symptoms, but it's far better to explain why.

Comment: I think it's more than that. `sizeof(std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty>` is `4` but `sizeof(std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty>)` is `8`.

Comment: @bolov - classes derived from a non-empty base are not empty. That `int` as the first element eliminates EBO.

Answer (score 5):

**tl,dr** This increased my respect for the library implementors even more. The rules they had to navigate to achieve this optimization for `std::tuple` is awe inspiring once you start thinking how could this be implemented.

---

Naturally I went on and played a little to see how this goes.

The setup:

```
struct Empty {};

template <class T> auto print_mem(const T& obj)
{
    cout << &obj << " - " << (&obj + 1) << " (" << sizeof(obj) << ")" << endl;
}
```

The test:

```
int main() {
    std::tuple<int> t_i;
    std::tuple<Empty> t_e;
    std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty> t_iee;
    std::tuple<Empty, Empty, int> t_eei;
    std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty, int> t_ieei;

    cout << "std::tuple<int>" << endl;
    print_mem(t_i);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "std::tuple<Empty>" << endl;
    print_mem(t_e);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty" << endl;
    print_mem(t_iee);
    print_mem(std::get<0>(t_iee));
    print_mem(std::get<1>(t_iee));
    print_mem(std::get<2>(t_iee));
    cout << endl;

    cout << "std::tuple<Empty, Empty, int>" << endl;
    print_mem(t_eei);
    print_mem(std::get<0>(t_eei));
    print_mem(std::get<1>(t_eei));
    print_mem(std::get<2>(t_eei));
    cout << endl;

    print_mem(t_ieei);
    print_mem(std::get<0>(t_ieei));
    print_mem(std::get<1>(t_ieei));
    print_mem(std::get<2>(t_ieei));
    print_mem(std::get<3>(t_ieei));
    cout << endl;
}
```

The results:

```
std::tuple<int>
0xff83ce64 - 0xff83ce68 (4)

std::tuple<Empty>
0xff83ce63 - 0xff83ce64 (1)

std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty
0xff83ce68 - 0xff83ce6c (4)
0xff83ce68 - 0xff83ce6c (4)
0xff83ce69 - 0xff83ce6a (1)
0xff83ce68 - 0xff83ce69 (1)

std::tuple<Empty, Empty, int>
0xff83ce6c - 0xff83ce74 (8)
0xff83ce70 - 0xff83ce71 (1)
0xff83ce6c - 0xff83ce6d (1)
0xff83ce6c - 0xff83ce70 (4)

std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty, int>
0xff83ce74 - 0xff83ce80 (12)
0xff83ce7c - 0xff83ce80 (4)
0xff83ce78 - 0xff83ce79 (1)
0xff83ce74 - 0xff83ce75 (1)
0xff83ce74 - 0xff83ce78 (4)
```

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/9pTHBq)

We can see right from the start that

```
sizeof(std:tuple<Empty>)                   == 1 (because the tuple cannot be empty)
sizeof(std:tuple<int>)                     == 4
sizeof(std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty)       == 4
sizeof(std::tuple<Empty, Empty, int)       == 8
sizeof(std::tuple<int, int>)               == 8
sizeof(std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty, int>) == 12
```

We can see that sometimes indeed no space is reserved for `Empty`, but in some circumstances `1 byte` is allocated for `Empty` (rest is padding). It looks like it can be `0` when `Empty` elements are the last elements.

Closely examining the addresses obtained via `get` we can see that never two `Empty` tuple elements have the same address (which is in line with the rule above), even if those addresses (of `Empty`) appear to be *inside* the `int` element. Moreover no address of an `Empty` element is outside the memory location of the container tuple.

This got me thinking: what if we have more trailing `Empty` than `sizeof(int)`. Would that increase the sizeof the tuple? Indeed it does:

```
sizeof(std::tuple<int>)                                         // 4
sizeof(std::tuple<int, Empty>)                                  // 4
sizeof(std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty>)                           // 4
sizeof(std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty, Empty>)                    // 4
sizeof(std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty>)             // 4
sizeof(std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty>)      // 8 yep. Magic
```

One final note: Is is OK to have "phantom" addresses for `Empty` elements (they appear to "share" the memory with the `int` element). Since `Empty` is an... well... empty class, it has no non-static data members, which means that the memory obtained for them can not be accessed.

Comment: `This increased my respect for the library implementors even more.` Which ones? Which library produced these results?

Comment: @underscore_d ideone, so I guess gcc

Comment: Yeah, ideone where it says `Language: C++` has a tooltip saying `gcc 5.1`, so that'll be `libstdc++`. Which is what I use, so that's good to know. :D

Comment: this is from what I could observe. A more insightful and/or language-layery answer would be awesome.

Comment: fyi: results on clang/libc++ a little different: std::tuple<int>(4)

std::tuple<Empty>(1)

std::tuple<int, Empty, Empty(8)(4)(1)(1)

std::tuple<Empty, Empty, int>(4)(1)(1)(4)

0x7fff5fbff568 - 0x7fff5fbff570 (8)(4)(1)(1)(4)